# 'd$' or 'd^' does not work when '$' or '^' is mapped to '<C-l>' or '<C-h>'

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to change the key mappings:

`$` => `<C-l>`

`^` => `<C-h>`

`d$` or `d^` does what they have to do (e.g., `d^` deletes from the current cursor to the beginning of the first char in the line).

However, after changing key mappings, `d<C-l>` or `d<C-h>` does not do what I expected.

What causes this problems?

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I need to use onoremap. I only changed the mapping for the normal mode. I have thought that it should work for operator pending mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need extra `onoremap` mappings for Operator-pending mode.

```
onoremap <C-L> $
onoremap <C-H> ^
```

Operator-pending mode gets triggered after a command such as `d` or `y` or `c` which takes a motion or text object to act on.

See [`:help omap-info`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#omap-info) for more details.